# How can i get the name of a variable which is stored in a list

Tags: java, variables, arraylist

I have the variable

```
int x = 2;
```

and the list:

```
ArrayList <Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>;
```

how can I get the name of

```
al.get (0)
```

so the name of the variable, `x` ?

Comment: Care to share the reason for wanting this? There will be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to keep a name stored with a value, try using a class:

```
public class MyClass {

    private String name;

    private int value;

    public MyClass(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now you can make a list that takes `MyClass`. You can then find out what name you gave to that value by calling its getters

```
ArrayList<MyClass> al = new ArrayList<MyClass>;
MyClass x = new MyClass("x", 2);
al.add(x);
System.out.println(al.get(0).getName());
System.out.println(al.get(0).getValue());
```

---

Or  you could use a map:

```
Map<String, Integer> al = new HashMap<>();
al.put("x", 2);
System.out.println(al.get("x")); // prints 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It is not the variable that is stored in the list; it is the value of the variable at the moment of storing.